# Core Bluetooth Optional Type not CBCentralmanager

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, xcode7

I'm working on a project including CoreBluetooth. I researched about that topic and found some tutorials on the web.

Now I recreated some of these tutorials and in almost every method I'm getting the following error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CBCentralManager'

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    if let central = central{ //Here is the error line
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
            print("Bluetooth ON")
        }
        else {
            // Can have different conditions for all states if needed - print generic message for now
            print("Bluetooth switched off or not initialized")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CBCentralManager` that is passed to the delegate method is not an optional - it has no `?` suffix, so you don't need to unwrap it.  This is what the error is telling you - you are trying to unwrap a variable that is not an optional.

You can just say

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        print("Bluetooth ON")
    }
    else {
        // Can have different conditions for all states if needed - print generic message for now
        print("Bluetooth switched off or not initialized")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It finally works perfectly. So happy now.